# useState returning empty array

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, strapi

I have this very simple code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import api from "../assets/services/api.js";

const Teste = () => {
    const [searchBand, setSearchBand] = useState("");
    const [bands, setBands] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const loadBands = async () => {
            const response = await api.get();
            setBands(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(bands);
        };
        loadBands();
    }, []);
```

that fetches data from Strapi. Thing is: **bands** only returns an empty array and I need that data to be mapped, so I can display it.

Here is the image:

[image: console image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: React update the state async so putting console after setting the state will not print the latest update value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because state only render when component re-render. So put `console.log(bands);` outside the `useEffect` to see the new value when the component render

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadBands = async () => {
        const response = await api.get();
        setBands(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
    };
    loadBands();
}, []);

console.log(bands);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!